# manage_users_custom_columns filter not firing callback functions

Tags: filters, user-meta, columns

I have added some custom columns to users table using the following function

```
    public function modify_users_columns( $column_headers ) {
    //Remove email, role, and posts column
    unset( $column_headers['email'], $column_headers['role'], $column_headers['posts'] );
    //Add sponsor id, level1 and level2 columns
    $column_headers['sponsor_id'] = 'Sponsor ID';
    $column_headers['level1'] = 'Level 1';
    $column_headers['level2'] = 'Level 2';
    return $column_headers;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', $plugin_admin, 'modify_users_columns' );
```

Then I am trying to populate these columns using custom user meta using following function

```
    public function display_custom_users_columns_data( $output, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'sponsor_id':
            return get_user_meta($user_id, 'sponsor_id', true);
            break;
        case 'level1':
            return get_user_meta($user_id, 'level1', true);
            break;
        case 'level2' :
            return get_user_meta($user_id, 'level2', true);
        default:
    }
    return $output;
} 
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_columns', $plugin_admin, 'display_custom_users_columns_data', 10, 3 );
```

The first function works correctly and my custom columns are displayed.
However the second function is not working, no matter how I return the $output variable

Someone reported this bug here but it was closed, I don't know?
[manage_users_custom_column filter not working](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10585)

Comment: there is no "s" at the end of the filter "manage_users_custom_column" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong filter name by adding an 's' in manage_users_custom_columns. The correct filter name is without 's' : manage_users_custom_column.
This was pointed out in the comments by @mmm.

Answer (score -3):

Try this....

```
case 'level1' :
  $level1 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'level1', true );
  echo $level1;
break;
```

Comment: Still not working. I tried returning string values directly without switch statements, but still not working

Comment: Abson Reavs, this cannot work. This filter need that the value is returned and not echoed.